# Looping on an interval of audio element with scalajs-react

Tags: scala, audio, reactjs, scala.js, scalajs-react

I want to build a little component containing an `audio` element, which capable of looping on an interval. The two ends of the interval would be a defined as properties of the component. As the `timeUpdate` event don't have the necessarily precision (I want at least 33Hz guaranteed), I decided to use a backend with `TimerSupport`, and just set the `currentTime` back to the starting point once it passes the end of the interval.

```
val AudioRef = Ref[Audio]("audio")
class PlayerBackend extends TimerSupport
val AudioPlayer = ReactComponentB[String]("AudioPlayer")
  .initialState(0L)
    .backend(i => new PlayerBackend())
  .render_P(url => {
    <.audio(
       ^.ref := AudioRef,
      ^.autoPlay  := true,
      ^.controls  := true,
      <.source(^.src := "http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3"),
      "Your browser does not support the audio element."
    )
  })
  .componentDidMount({ c =>
    c.backend.setInterval(Callback.log({
      if (AudioRef(c).isDefined) ({
        AudioRef(c).get.currentTime
      }) else "nothing"
    }), 1000 millisecond)
  }).configure(TimerSupport.install)
  .build
```

It this little example I just want to print the current position of the player, but for some reason (the callback closes over a copy of the backend context at the time when the component mounts?) the `AudioRef(c)` points to an old version of the audio element. Any idea how to fix this? I'm also interested in other designs, as I'm not really experienced neither with ScalaJS nor React.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the `log` call that evaluates its parameter only once, resulting in a single value that is then logged over and over again. The correct code would be something like this:

```
.componentDidMount({ c =>
  c.backend.setInterval(CallbackTo[Double] {
    if (AudioRef(c).isDefined) ({
      AudioRef(c).get.currentTime
    }) else 0
  } >>= Callback.log, 1000 millisecond)
})
```

It creates a callback that extracts the `currentTime` value (or nothing) and then flatMaps to another callback that logs that value.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up setting the `currentTime` property by getting the audio element based on its `id` in a `Callback`, so my solution currently looks like this:

```
class PlayerBackend($: BackendScope[String, Unit]) extends TimerSupport
val AudioPlayer = ReactComponentB[String]("AudioPlayer")
  .initialState(())
    .backend(i => new PlayerBackend(i))
  .render_P(url => {
    <.audio(
      ^.id := "audio",
      ^.autoPlay  := true,
      ^.controls  := true,
      <.source(^.src := "http://www.stephaniequinn.com/Music/Allegro%20from%20Duet%20in%20C%20Major.mp3"),
      "Your browser does not support the audio element."
    )
  })
  .componentDidMount({ c =>
    c.backend.setInterval(
      Callback({document.getElementById("audio").asInstanceOf[Audio].currentTime = 5.0}) ,
      1 seconds
    )
})
.configure(TimerSupport.install)
.build
```